# on Android, wrapper method for logging Crashlytics events with calling class as source of event

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a utility method inside Utility.class which is a wrapper for sending Crashlytics events.

```
public static void logCrashlyticsEvent(String message) {
     ...
     Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(new Exception(message));
     ...
}
```

The issue is whenever I use it from another class the Crashlytics dashboard shows the source for the event as Utility.class like this:

```
Utility.java line 106
com.myApp.util.Utility.logCrashlyticsEvent
```

Instead of the showing the it as the actual class who called it.

Is there a way wrap the call to Crashlytics so it will still show the calling class as the source for the event?

Thanks.

Edit:
Just to improve on @Andre Classen solution.

```
public static void logCrashlyticsEvent(HandledException e) {
    Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);
    Timber.e("Message: %s", e.getMessage());
    // More stuff
}
```

HandledException:

```
public class HandledException extends Exception {
    public HandledException(@NonNull String message, Object... args) {
         super(String.format(message, args));
}
```

}

Usage:

```
Utility.logCrashlyticsEvent(new HandledException("Cast exception, input value1: %s, value2: %s", someValue, anotherValue));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new Exception instead of logging the source exception , so the solution is easy:

```
public static void logCrashlyticsEvent(Exception e) {
.
.
     Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);
.
.
}
```

To use it:

```
    try{
        String s=null;
        int size=toString().length();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){
        com.myApp.util.Utility.logCrashlyticsEvent(e);
    }
```

This way the exception is logged the way you want it.